# Angular2: Validate form without defining error messages at each input?

Tags: angular

I want `validate form` in `angular2`. I learn some document, and it will be define like this:

```html
<form [ngFormModel]="form">
        <input type="text" ngControl="username" />

        <p *ngIf="username.pending">Fetching data from the server...</p>

        <div *ngIf="username.dirty && !username.valid && !username.pending">
          <p *ngIf="username.errors.required">Username is required.</p>
          <p *ngIf="username.errors.startsWithNumber">Your username can't start with a number</p>
          <p *ngIf="username.errors.usernameTaken">This username is taken</p>
        </div>

        <button (click)="submitData()" [disabled]="!form.valid" class="btn btn-primary">Sumbit data</button>
</form>
```

```ts
constructor(private builder: FormBuilder) {

    this.username = new Control(
        "", 
        Validators.compose([Validators.required, UsernameValidator.startsWithNumber]),
        UsernameValidator.usernameTaken
    );

    this.form = builder.group({
        username:  this.username
    });
}
```

With each input I need to define many error messages. I think it's not good.
I want like jquery.validate, I just define `input` and the error messages will be auto render, like this

```html
<input required name="username" maxlength='8' pattern="^(?!\s|.*\s$).*$" ...>
```

Comment: You can create custom validators or directives that produce the error messages you want. I expect the material elements to be more opinionated and provide something that does that by default. I don't know jQuery and therefore it's unclear what exactly you are asking for.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer OP wants a plugin like feature where you don't have to write `error checks and html template` for every validation. `jquery.validate` does that thing. So I think she is asking for `code reduction`.

Comment: @A_Singh I know what the question is about in general, but it's not very concrete what the desired solution should look like. There are many ways that lead to Rome ;-)

Comment: Write a plugin and throw it in the answer, maybe :-P

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your support. In my post, I have to define one message for one error with each input. So I looking for a good solution, that I will insert error need to check into input field, and the error message will be auto display if invalid. This is just my thinking, and I need suggest form everybody.

Answer (score 3):

To reduce your code one approach could be to write a component.

Which will handle all the `condition checkings` and `error messages`

[This guy did a nice job here of implementing and explaining it.](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-form-builder-and-validation-management)

---

**HTML with Component would look like this**

```html
<input ngControl="email" id="email" />
<control-messages control="email"></control-messages>
```

and all the `dirty work` would go inside `control-messages` component.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you could leverage a dedicated component to do that. This component will all generic content like "label" and area for errors. An important point is the way to leverage `ng-content` to provide the form element (input, textarea, select) as an input of this component.

Another interesting thing is the ability to reference the control associated to this input from the component. This way, you will be able to transparently know / display validation errors associated with the form element.

Here is a sample implementation of such component. First the content of the associated template:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm" [ngClass]="{'has-error':state && !state.valid}">
  <label for="for"
    class="col-sm-3 control-label”>{{label}}</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <ng-content ></ng-content>
    <p *ngIf="state.pending">Fetching data from the server...</p>

    <div *ngIf="state.dirty && !state.valid && !state.pending">
      <p *ngIf="state.errors.required">Field is required.</p>
      <p *ngIf="state.errors.startsWithNumber">Your field can't start with a number</p>
      <p *ngIf="state.errors.usernameTaken">This field is taken</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the component itself

```
@Component({
  selector: 'field',
  templateUrl: 'field.html'
})
export class FormFieldComponent {
  @Input()
  label: string;

  @Input()
  feedback: boolean;

  @ContentChild(NgFormControl) state;

  (...)
}
```

Then you can use this component this way in your form:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="form">
  <field label="Name">
    <input type="text" [ngFormControl]="form.controls.username" />
  </field>

  <button (click)="submitData()" [disabled]="!form.valid" class="btn btn-primary">Sumbit data</button>
</form>
```

See this article (section "Form component for fields") for more details:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/17/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is to late to answer this but it might help others.
To overcome this issue I created following directive. This directive works fine for both template driven & reactive forms.

**What it does:**

1. Regular expression based validation (for both mandatory and
   non-mandatory fields).
2. Shows configured error message against
   regular expression.
3. Optionally you can pass field name as well to
   make you error message more user friendly.
4. works fine for text input, select & textarea elements

**How to use:**

Prepare configuration file.

**configiration file: error-configurations.ts**

```
export const errorConfiguration = {
    'alphaNum': {
        'regex': /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/,
        'msg': 'LABEL should contain only alpaha numeric values'
    },
    'email': {
        'regex': /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$/,
        'msg': 'LABEL is not valid email'
    }
};
```

In configuration file, specify your regular expression and their respective error messages. In error messages, "LABEL" would be replaced with field name if "easyLabel" attribute were specified.

In your element need to use it as follows:

Case 1> Mandatory email

```
    It will show following messages
        If field is empty : Field is mandatory
        If field is invalid email : Field is not valid demail ( this is from configuartion file LABEL is replaced with "Field" as easyLabel is not specified.)
```

Case 2> Non mandatory email

```
    It will show following message
        If field is invalid email : Field is not valid demail
```

Case 3> Specity field label for more user friendly error messages

```
    It will show following messages
        If field is empty : Email Address is mandatory
        If field is in valid email : Email Address is not valid email
```

**Directive file: easy-validator.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, forwardRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Validator, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';
import { errorConfiguration } from './error-configurations';    // use configuration file


@Directive({
    selector: '[easyValidate]',
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => EasyValidatorDirective), multi: true }
    ]
})
export class EasyValidatorDirective implements Validator {
    @Input('easyValidate') easyValidate: string;
    @Input('easyLabel') easyLabel;
    private isRequired: boolean;
    private patternName: string;
    private master;
    public easyConfig;
    constructor(
        public el: ElementRef
    ) {
        this.easyConfig = errorConfiguration;
        this.easyConfig['REQ'] = {'msg' : 'LABEL is mandatory'};


        if (!('remove' in Element.prototype)) {
            Element.prototype.remove = function () {
                if (this.parentNode) {
                    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
                }
            };
        }
    }
    validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } {
        let val = control.value;
        let temp_arr = this.easyValidate.split('|');
        this.isRequired = temp_arr[0] === 'REQ';
        this.patternName = temp_arr.length > 0 ? temp_arr[1] : '';
        if (this.isRequired) {
            this.el.nativeElement.addEventListener('blur', () => this.getErrorMsgElement().classList.remove('hide'), false);

            if (val == '' || val == null || val.toString().trim() == '') {
                this.showErrorMsg('REQ');
                return {
                    msoValidateRequired: false 
                };
            }
        }
        if (this.patternName !== '' && ((val != '' && val != null))) {
            this.el.nativeElement.addEventListener('blur', () => this.getErrorMsgElement().classList.remove('hide'), false);
            this.el.nativeElement.addEventListener('keydown', () => this.getErrorMsgElement().classList.remove('hide'), false);
            this.el.nativeElement.addEventListener('change', () => this.getErrorMsgElement().classList.remove('hide'), false);

            if (this.getRegEx(this.patternName)) {
                let pattern: RegExp = this.getRegEx(this.patternName);
                if (pattern && !pattern.test(val) && val != '') {
                    this.showErrorMsg(this.patternName);
                    return {
                        msoValidatePattern: false
                    };
                }
            }

        }

        this.removeErrorMsgElement();
        return null;
    }

    private showErrorMsg(msgKey: string) {
        this.getErrorMsgElement().innerHTML = this.getErrorMsg(msgKey);
    }
    private getErrorMsgElement() {
        let errorElementList = this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('error-span');
        return errorElementList.length ? errorElementList[0] : this.createErrorElement();
    }

    private createErrorElement() {
        let errorSpan = document.createElement('span');
        errorSpan.setAttribute('class', 'text-danger error-span hide');
        return this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.appendChild(errorSpan);
    }
    private removeErrorMsgElement() {
        this.getErrorMsgElement().remove();
    }
    private getErrorMsg(msgKey: string) {
        let errMsg: string = this.getConfigMsg(msgKey) ? this.getConfigMsg(msgKey) : 'Invalid Value';

        errMsg = errMsg.replace('LABEL', (this.easyLabel ? this.easyLabel : 'Field'));
        return errMsg;
    }

    getRegEx(regKey: string) {
        if (typeof this.easyConfig[regKey] !== 'undefined') {
            return this.easyConfig[regKey]['regex'];
        }
        return false;
    }

    getConfigMsg(regKey: string) {
        if (typeof this.easyConfig[regKey] !== 'undefined') {
            return this.easyConfig[regKey]['msg'];
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

You need to declare this directive in your module to use it.

**Module file: app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, .... , EasyValidatorDirective
  ],
  imports: [    ...  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```